# Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho **3** tabelas de `funcionário`, `apontamentos` e `horastrabalhadas`.

Meu relacionamento é `hasmany` **1** funcionário tem vários `apontamentos`.
Quando mostro o resultado com um `dd()` vem os dados do funcionário duas vezes e as `horastrabalhadas` em branco. Tem inverter  de `hasMany` para `belongTo` para ver se minha lógica estava errada mas veio a mesma coisa.

Tabela `apontamentos`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apontamentos ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT, apontamento varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT
NULL, created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, updated_at timestamp
NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Tabela `equipetecnicas`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipetecnicas ( id int(10) unsigned NOT
NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, matricula int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, nome
varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, cargo varchar(150)
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, cargahoraria int(10) unsigned
NOT NULL, nomeequipe varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT
NULL, created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, updated_at timestamp
NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

Tabela `hss`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hhs ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT, idequipe int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, idapontamento
int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, dataapontamento datetime NOT NULL,
horaapontamentoinicio time NOT NULL, horaapontamentofim time NOT NULL,
numeroos int(11) NOT NULL, created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY
hhs_idequipe_foreign (idequipe), KEY hhs_idapontamento_foreign
(idapontamento) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Já aconteceu algo semelhante com alguém?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54218/discussion-on-question-by-marcos-birro-como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-lar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>**Relacionamento 1:N Laravel**</sup>

### Relacionamentos:

> `Apontamentos`

```
class Apontamentos extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('apontamento');
    protected $table = 'apontamentos';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function hhs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Hhs::class, 'idapontamento', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

> `Equipetecnicas`

```
class Equipetecnicas extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('matricula','nome','cargo','cargahoraria','nomeequipe');
    protected $table = 'equipetecnicas';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';    
    
    public function hhs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Hhs::class, 'idequipe', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

> `Hhs`

```
class Hhs extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('idequipe','idapontamento','dataapontamento',
            'horaapontamentoinicio','horaapontamentofim','numeroos');
    protected $table = 'hhs';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 

    public function apontamento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Apontamentos::class, 'idapontamento', 'id');
    }

    public function equipetecnicas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Equipetecnicas::class, 'idequipe', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

*Chamando os relacionamentos:*

Utilize [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean) para carregar os relacionamentos

***Exemplo 1*** - `Equipetecnicas`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $ep = new App\Models\Equipetecnicas();
    $result = $ep->with('hhs.apontamento')
               ->where('id',$id)
               ->first();
}
```

> *Saída:*

```
App\Models\Equipetecnicas {#740
 id: 1,
 matricula: 1,
 nome: "Nome 1",
 cargo: "Administrador",
 cargahoraria: 120,
 nomeequipe: "Equipe 1",
 created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
 updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
 hhs: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#760
   all: [
     App\Models\Hhs {#762
       id: 1,
       idequipe: 1,
       idapontamento: 1,
       dataapontamento: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
       horaapontamentoinicio: "13:00:00",
       horaapontamentofim: "14:00:00",
       numeroos: 1,
       created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
       updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
       apontamento: App\Models\Apontamentos {#767
         id: 1,
         apontamento: "Apontamento 1",
         created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
         updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
       },
     },
   ],
 },
}
```

***Exemplo 2*** - `Hhs`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $hhs = new App\Models\Hhs();
    $result = $hhs->with('apontamento')
                  ->with('equipetecnicas')
                  ->where('id',$id)
                  ->first();
}
```

> *Saida:*

```
App\Models\Hhs {#746
  id: 2,
  idequipe: 2,
  idapontamento: 2,
  dataapontamento: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
  horaapontamentoinicio: "15:00:00",
  horaapontamentofim: "16:00:00",
  numeroos: 2,
  created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
  updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
  apontamento: App\Models\Apontamentos {#752
    id: 2,
    apontamento: "Apontamento 2",
    created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
    updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
  },
  equipetecnicas: App\Models\Equipetecnicas {#753
    id: 2,
    matricula: 2,
    nome: "Nome 2",
    cargo: "Gerente",
    cargahoraria: 240,
    nomeequipe: "Equipe 2",
    created_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
   updated_at: "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
 },
}
```

<sub>*Leitura obrigatória:* Leia todo esse [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) que trata do [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries), na construção de `SQL` a partir do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)
- [Laravel - Eloquent “Has”, “With”, “WhereHas” - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)
- [Laravel Eloquent with and find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864010/laravel-eloquent-with-and-find)
- [Relacionamento entre Tabelas no Laravel](https://magazine.softerize.com.br/tutoriais/php/laravel/relacionamento-entre-tabelas-laravel)

Comment: Vou ter que testar mais tarde e comento aqui. Surgiu demanda urgente.

Comment: Virgílio, eu não estou sabendo como fazer. Pode me dizer como devo chamar este método? Eu simplesmente estou dando um retorno usando o método show selecionando um membro da equipetecnica na esperança que seja mostrado os relacionamentos de horas trabalhadas (hh) junto com apontamento (descrição do apontamento).

Comment: @MarcosBirro acredito que com esses dois exemplo consiga entender como se faz esse carregamento das relação, existe por `inner join` sim existe, coloquei então esse [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) para a sua leitura que lá tem tudo que precisa. Se tiver mais dúvidas acredito que tenha que abrir nova pergunta essa em questão foi respondido sua duvida inicial.

Comment: @JuniorRamoty não entendi, se quiser talvez abra um questionamento!