# RelationsShips Larval 5.4 acessando dados do busca com with?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, relacionamento

Tenho um relacionamento de `One To Many`, queria saber como faço para acessar dados das duas tabela.

***Veja:***

```
Album::with('imagemAlbums')->where('departamento_id', $id)->get();
```

Retorno do `dd()`

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora na minha View eu quero acessar os dados da tabela Algum e da tabela 
`imagemAlbum` onde a `imagemAlbum` se relaciona. Quando eu faço o `foreach` eu acesso os dados do `Album`, e como faço para acessar os outros dados da outra tabela que no caso é o `imagemAlbum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dessa forma:

```
$albuns = Album::with('imagemAlbums')
               ->where('departamento_id', $id)->get();

foreach($albuns as $album)
{
     $album-> ... ; // campos
     foreach($album->imagemAlbum as $imagem)
     {
         $imagem-> ... ; // campos
     }
}
```

***Porque isso acontece?***

Os resultados obtido é uma [coleção](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) de **Album**, que em cada **Album** tem uma [coleção](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) de **ImagemAlbum**.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)
- [Laravel - Eloquent “Has”, “With”, “WhereHas” - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)
- [Laravel Eloquent with and find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864010/laravel-eloquent-with-and-find)

Comment: Perfeita a explicação. Muito obrigado