# Exemplo Prático de se Trabalhar com Eloquent no Laravel 5.6 (Relacionamentos)

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma entidade que é funcionários e outras 3 tabelas que são *Setor*, *Cargo* e *Departamento* e o relacionamento é de **1** para **N** (ou seja as chaves primárias dessas 3 tabelas devem virar estrangeiras na tabela funcionário).

Na minha `View` no cadastro de funcionário tem um `select` para cada uma dessas entidades (*Cargo*, *Setor* e *Dpt*) que deve ser populado com os registros já cadastrados no banco.

Porém não consegui fazer a relação e não sei como poderia chamar o método
na `View`. Dá forma que fiz aqui ele apareceu o id do cargo e não o nome do cargo e quando apaguei o registro da `View` saiu do select, ou seja estou fazendo errado puxando da `View` e não do banco como deveria ser. Poderiam me ajudar?

Vou postar a Model de Funcionário e de Cargo e também a parte da `View`
onde "preencho" o select

MODEL DE FUNCIONÁRIO

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Treinamento;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Funcionario extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'nome_funcionario', 'email_funcionario', 'instrutor', 

    ];  

         protected $guarded = [

            'id', 'cargos_id', 'setors_id', 'departamentos_id' 

            ];  
                protected $table = 'funcionarios';


    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



}
```

MODEL DE CARGO

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Treinamento;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Cargo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome_cargo'
    ];
    protected $table = 'cargos';


    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



}
```

PARTE DA VIEW (SELECT DE CARGO)

```
div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
             <strong>Selecione o Cargo</strong>
          <select name="cargos_id" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>

       @foreach ($classcargo_array as $cargos_id)
        <option value="{{$cargos_id->id}}" > {{$cargos_id->nome_cargo}} 
        </option>
               @endforeach 
                 </select>    

                        </div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para relações Um-para-Muitos inversa, você utiliza a função de relacionamento `belongsTo`, dessa forma na classe `Funcionario`:

```
public function cargo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Treinamento\Cargo::class, 'cargos_id', 'id');
    // O primeiro parametro é a Model(Cargo) que se relaciona.
    // O segundo, é a foreign key, coluna nessa classe(Funcionario) que identifica a Model.
    // O terceiro, é a local key, a coluna na Model(Cargo) que identifica ela.
}
```

Dessa forma, quando você carregar um `Funcionario` e quiser obter as informações do `Cargo` dele, você utiliza o `->` pois a relação `belongsTo` retorna uma instância da classe `Cargo`, assim:

```
$funcionario->cargo->nome_cargo
```

Detalhe, você define uma função para a relação mas para utilizar você chama ele como se a função fosse uma propriedade.

Para o `Cargo` obter os `Funcionario` relacionados a ele, você usaria a relação Um-para-Muitos`hasMany` e adicionaria a função a seguir na classe do `Cargo`:

```
public function funcionarios()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Treinamento\Funcionario::class, 'cargos_id', 'id');
    // O primeiro parametro é a Model(Funcionario) que se relaciona.
    // O segundo, é a foreign key, coluna na Model(Funcionario) que identifica essa classe.
    // O terceiro, é a local key, a coluna nessa classe(Cargo) que identifica ela.
}
```

E para manipular os `Funcionario` relacionados com o `Cargo`, você utiliza o `foreach` pois a relação `hasMany` retorna uma coleção de `Funcionario`, assim:

```
foreach($cargo->funcionarios as $funcionario){
    // Algum código...
}
```

---

Quanto a sua `view`, se você quer obter todos `Cargo` adicionados e exibir eles na tag `option`, você usa o seguinte código na função no seu `Controller` em que está retornando a `view` de cadastro de `Funcionario`:

```
...
$cargos = \App\Models\Treinamento\Cargo::all();
return view('view_de_cadastro_de_funcionario', compact('cargos'));
```

E na sua `view`, você exibe eles da mesma forma como você escreveu na resposta com os nomes alterados, assim:

```
@foreach ($cargos as $cargo)
    <option value="{{ $cargo->id }}">{{ $cargo->nome_cargo }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius. Acho que ainda estou fazendo algo errado porque tive o retorno desse erro na view: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: cargos Undefined variable: cargos

Comment: @DevPHP Foi erro meu, havia esquecido de adicionar a função `compact`, agora eu corrigi na resposta e agora deve funcionar sem problemas. Para passar valores para a view, tipo a variável `$cargos`, o segundo parâmetro deve ser assim ['cargos' => $cargos]. Usando o `helper` `compact` ele faz esse processo automaticamente.

Comment: Só uma pequena dica. O compact é uma função nativa do PHP e não um helper do laravel. https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php