# Relacionamento Eloquent / Laravel Onetomany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o Laravel 5.7 para criar um sistema de pedidos. Portanto tenho 3 tabelas: clientes, produtos e pedidos.

Meu Banco de dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por enquanto minhas migrations estão assim:
**Migrations:**
migration clientes:

```
    Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('nome_completo');
        $table->text('rua');
        $table->text('numero');
        $table->text('bairro');
        $table->text('email');
        $table->text('tel');
        $table->text('empresa');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

migration produtos:

```
Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('nome');
        $table->float('valor');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

migration pedidos:

```
Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cliente_id')
          ->references('id')->on('clientes');
        $table->integer('produto_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('produto_id')
          ->references('id')->on('produtos');
        $table->integer('quantidade');
        $table->float('total', 8, 2);
        $table->boolean('pago');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Models:**
App\Produto

```
public function pedidos()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Pedidos::class);
}
```

App\Cliente

```
public function pedidos()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Pedidos::class);
}
```

App\Pedidos

```
protected $table = 'pedidos';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function clientes()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
 }

 public function produtos()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Produto::class);
   }
```

Agora como ficariam os controllers? Gostaria de recuperar TODOS os pedidos! Já tentei

```
$pedidos = Pedido::all()->produtos;
```

e nada!

A tabela que será exibida na view de Pedidos deveria conter o nome do cliente, nome do produto, a quantidade de cada produto e o valor total.

Comment: Tenta usar assim `Pedido::with('produtos')->get();`

Comment: @adventistaam foi isso mesmo cara. Só que depois de revirar a documentação do Laravel percebi que seria Many To Many o relacionamento e alterei minhas models para $this->belongsToMany e no meu controller fiz o que vc me falou, porém dessa forma: $pedidos = Pedido::with('produtos')->with('clientes')->get();

Comment: @adventistaam agora só me resta mostrar os dados na view!! kkk 
`foreach ($pedidos as $pedido) {
            echo "Nome do Produto: ".$pedido->produtos->nome;
            echo "Nome do cliente: ".$pedido->clientes->nome_completo;
        }`

Comment: seria `@foreach @endforeach`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado @adventistaam

O problema da VIEW e dos relacionamentos foram resolvidos.
Agora começarei os creates e updates!

**Model Pedido**

```
public function clientes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente', 'pedidos', 'cliente_id', 'id');
}

public function produtos()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto', 'pedidos', 'produto_id', 'id');
  }
```

**Model Cliente e Produto**

```
public function pedidos()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Pedido::class);
}
```

**View index**

```
 @foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
                <tr>
                  <td >{{ $pedido->id }}</td>
                  <td >{{ $pedido->clientes[0]->nome_completo }}</td>
                  <td >{{ $pedido->clientes[0]->rua }}, {{ $pedido->clientes[0]->numero }} - {{ $pedido->clientes[0]->bairro }} </td>
                  <td>{{ $pedido->produtos[0]->nome }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $pedido->quantidade }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $pedido->produtos[0]->valor }}</td>
                  <td>{{ date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($pedido->created_at)) }}</td>
                  <td> @if ($pedido->pago == 1)
                    Pago
                  @else
                    Débito
                  @endif</td>
                  <td>
                    <ul class="list-inline list-small">
                          <li class="list-inline-item"><a title="Editar" href="{{ route('pedidos.edit', ['pedido' => $pedido->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a></li>
                          <li title="Excluir" class="list-inline-item">
                            <form  action="{{ route('pedidos.destroy', ['pedido' => $pedido->id]) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('\nTem certeza que deseja excluir esta nota?'); return false;" method="post">
                              {{ csrf_field() }}
                              {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt "></span></button>
                          </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu costumo popular,e preparar essas ações tudo pelo jquery