# Relacionamento único entre duas tabelas

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Então, estou com essas tabelas: `users`, `chat_rooms` and `chat_room_allowed_users`.

```
users
    id
    ...

chat_rooms
    id
    key
    user_host
    ...
    
chat_room_allowed_users
    id
    room_key
    user_allowed
    ...
```

O que estou tentando fazer, é retornar todos os `chat_rooms` relacionados com o `Auth::user()`, seja ele o host de um canal e/ou sendo algum participante de outro(s) canal(is).

Eu sei que dá para retornar esse resultado usando as queries do Eloquent, mas para deixar mais prático, estou tentando fazer isso com apenas um relacionamento.

Por agora, estou usando dois relacionamentos distintos (`Auth::user()->chat_rooms_hosted` e `Auth::user()->chat_rooms_allowed`) e dando um merge entre elas antes de passar para a view.

```
class User {
    ...

    public function chat_rooms_hosted(){
        return $this->hasMany(ChatRoom::class, 'user_host', 'id');
    }

    public function chat_rooms_allowed(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ChatRoomUserAllowed::class, 'id', 'user_allowed');
    }
}
```

É possível fazer esse relacionamento ou compensa usar a query do Eloquent mesmo?

Exemplo figurado:

```
class User {
    ...

    public function chat_rooms(){
        // A = $this->hasMany(ChatRoom::class, 'user_host', 'id');
        // B = $this->belongsTo(ChatRoomUserAllowed::class, 'id', 'user_allowed);
        // relacionamento = uniãoEntre(A e B);
        // return relacionamento;
    }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2)

Comment: Na real... não muito. Minha intenção é unir 2 relacionamentos (que já funcionam de forma independente) em um único e retornar esse relacionamento.

Comment: é a mesma ideia Samuel Vasconcellos

Comment: Acabei optando pelo appending values to JSON e funcionou, achei mais prático. Aliás, obrigado pela sugestão ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você poderia adicionar um atributo customizado e inserir essa lógica dentro dele.

[Appending values to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Ou simplesmente criar um método dentro do seu model User:

```php
public function chats ()
{
     // Aqui você coloca toda a lógica e retorna o valor
}
```

Então é só chamar o método `Auth::user()->chats()`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Beleza, vou testar aqui! Nunca usei o Appending values. Valeu Lucas!